# i want to record the console output from a command and save it as a variable in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I want to run this command which would output the WiFi networks in range of the device, and save all the networks as a variable, all i know so far is this:

```
Dim networks
set oShell = createobject("wscript.shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /C netsh wlan show profiles"
```

But unfortunatley i need some way of recording it but i dont know how, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `.Run` method does not give access to the output of the executed program. You need to use the `Exec` method and retrieve the output of the program from the `StdOut` property.

```
Option Explicit

Dim shell, executed, buffer

    rem Instantiate the needed component to launch another executable
    Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    rem If you expect a lot of data from the output of the command
    rem or if you need separate lines
    Set executed = shell.Exec("netsh wlan show profiles")
    Do While Not executed.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        buffer = executed.StdOut.ReadLine()
        Call WScript.Echo( buffer )
    Loop

    rem For short outputs, you can retrieve all the data in one call
    Set executed = shell.Exec("netsh wlan show profiles")
    buffer = executed.StdOut.ReadAll()
    Call WScript.Echo( buffer )
```